# CSS Hover slide out issue

Tags: html, css

I have 2 slide out menus one on either side of the page. They both slide out perfectly on hover, but for some reason when I hover over the right hand slide out the left one slides out as well. I am new to coding so cannot see why this is happening.

Here is my HTML and CSS

CSS:

```
#slideout {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
#slideout_inner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: -268px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
#slideout:hover {
    left: 250px;
}
#slideout:hover #slideout_inner {
    left: 0;
}
#slideout2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
#slideout_inner2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: -268px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
#slideout2:hover {
    right: 268px;
}
#slideout2:hover #slideout_inner2 {
    right: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slideout">
    <img src="Images/pre-hover.gif" width="70" height="80" />
    <div id="slideout_inner">
        <img src="Images/contact-about.gif" width="268" height="80" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
        <map name="Map" id="Map">
            <area shape="rect" coords="10,7,262,37" href="Contact.html" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="8,48,266,76" href="About.html" />
        </map>
    </div>

<div id="slideout2">
    <img src="Images/pre-hover2.gif" width="70" height="167" />
    <div id="slideout_inner2">
        <img src="Images/slideout.gif" width="268" height="167" />
    </div>
```

If somebody could please assist me it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing closing `</div>` tags:

```
<div id="slideout">
    <img src="Images/pre-hover.gif" width="70" height="80" />
    <div id="slideout_inner">
        <img src="Images/contact-about.gif" width="268" height="80" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
        <map name="Map" id="Map">
            <area shape="rect" coords="10,7,262,37" href="Contact.html" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="8,48,266,76" href="About.html" />
        </map>
    </div>

</div> <!-- Here -->

<div id="slideout2">
    <img src="Images/pre-hover2.gif" width="70" height="167" />
    <div id="slideout_inner2">
        <img src="Images/slideout.gif" width="268" height="167" />
    </div>

</div> <!-- And here -->
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZawMZ/2/)

[Indenting your code](http://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/formatting-and-indenting-your-html/) as you go along keeps your code tidy, and can help you catch issues before they become bugs.

Answer (score 0):

When coding it helps to add tabs to your code so you can see the logical flow, basically slideout2 was contained within slideout, here's your old code with tabs:

```
<div id="slideout">
    <img src="Images/pre-hover.gif" width="70" height="80" />
    <div id="slideout_inner">
        <img src="Images/contact-about.gif" width="268" height="80" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
        <map name="Map" id="Map">
            <area shape="rect" coords="10,7,262,37" href="Contact.html" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="8,48,266,76" href="About.html" />
        </map>
    </div>
        <div id="slideout2">
            <img src="Images/pre-hover2.gif" width="70" height="167" />
        <div id="slideout_inner2">
        <img src="Images/slideout.gif" width="268" height="167" />
        </div>
```

And the new code, see how the structure has changed:

```
<div id="slideout">
    <img src="Images/pre-hover.gif" width="70" height="80" />
    <div id="slideout_inner">
        <img src="Images/contact-about.gif" width="268" height="80" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
        <map name="Map" id="Map">
            <area shape="rect" coords="10,7,262,37" href="Contact.html" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="8,48,266,76" href="About.html" />
        </map>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="slideout2">
    <img src="Images/pre-hover2.gif" width="70" height="167" />
    <div id="slideout_inner2">
        <img src="Images/slideout.gif" width="268" height="167" />
    </div>
</div>
```